# Converting from java.util.List to spark dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am still very new to spark and scala, but very familiar with Java. I have some java jar that has a function that returns an List (java.util.List) of Integers, but I want to convert these to a spark dataset so I can append it to another column and then perform a join. Is there any easy way to do this? I've tried things similar to this code:

```
val testDSArray : java.util.List[Integer] = new util.ArrayList[Integer]()
testDSArray.add(4)
testDSArray.add(7)
testDSArray.add(10)

val testDS : Dataset[Integer] = spark.createDataset(testDSArray, Encoders.INT())
```

but it gives me compiler errors (cannot resolve overloaded method)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [type signature](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@createDataset[T](data:java.util.List[T])(implicitevidence$6:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[T]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]) you will see that in **Scala** the encoder is passed in a second *(and implicit)* parameter list.

You may:

Pass it in another parameter list.

```
val testDS = spark.createDataset(testDSArray)(Encoders.INT)
```

Don't pass it, and leave the **Scala**'s implicit mechanism resolves it.

```
import spark.implicits._
val testDS = spark.createDataset(testDSArray)
```

Convert the **Java**'s List to a **Scala**'s one first.

```
import collection.JavaConverters._
import spark.implicits._
val testDS = testDSArray.asScala.toDS()
```

Comment: One last followup question, is there a way to turn that dataset of integer to a dataset row?

Comment: @GeoffreySaunders you can use one of the `spark.createDataFrame` methods _(but the code will change a bit)_, or in the last example use  `toDF("colName")` instead. Or after having the `Dataset` call `toDF("colName")` in it.